# Periodically run query to transfer data between two SQL Servers

Tags: sql-server, data-transfer

I have two MS SQL Servers, let's call them **Source** and **Destination**. I need to bring some data from a database table in **Source** by making a simple query (a **Select** and a **Sum**) and bring the result to a database table in **Destination**.

I need to run the query **once a month** in order to have available the data in **Destination** to be used by an application.

I was thinking about doing it at **application layer** by creating a workflow (which is complex and not worth for such a simple issue) but I would like to know whether there is a easier option by using **SSIS** or any other tool. It is especially unclear to me how to set up the **trigger** to run the query and **where to place** the query code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just make use of the SQL Server Job scheduling functionality rather than writing your own triggering and handling logic.

And creating an SSIS package (or dtsx file) is a good option. You might just need to do an import/export wizard out of the database tasks, save it as a reusable SSIS package and then use a scheduled job to run it once a month.

So, the job is your trigger and also calls the SSIS import/export package to run... your query code.

Comment: Forget job scheduling - Replication is a built-in feature.

Comment: @Joel: Jobs are a built-in feature as well. Replication would work too but I think it's overkill in this case and would actually be tougher to use with a *Sum* aggregate which was mentioned as a requirement by the OP. Using jobs also allows you to just manage a single job object on one server. Replication requires non-trivial configuration on both ends.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Shall I use the Execute Package Utility?

Comment: and where shall I place and execute the package? Source or Destination server?

Comment: @Francesco: You shouldn't need any special utility if you create a job to run your package. That will be your utility. And I would put the job on the "destination" server. It's often easier and less problematic to pull (instead of pushing.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a scheduled job/SSIS solution would be to create a *view* in **Destination** that maps back to **Source** via a *linked server* and *openrowset* call.  This way you don't really need to move the data, and can access it when you like in real-time from **Source**.